# Incrementar ou decrementar var no resize window

Tags: javascript

Olá.
Eu tenho uma variável com o valor 0 e uma janela no tamanho 1000. Gostaria que no resize para tamanhos menores, 999, 998, 997, a variável se decrementasse ficando em -1, -2... E no resize para maior, ela se incrementasse, 1, 2... Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Mostre o que você está fazendo para termos uma ideia melhor do problema. Me parece algo simples mas pode ser que eu não tenha entendido o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Cria uma variável que guarde esse valor e junta um oscultador de evento para quando a janela mudar de tamanho. Precisas também de uma maneira de ir buscar informação do tamanho atual da janela. Não percebo bem na tua pergunta se queres a *largura* (x) ou a *altura* (y). Junto um exemplo que faz isso, calculando a largura mas com o código da altura também:

```
var janela = 0;
function medeJanela(){
    var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        y = w.innerHeight|| e.clientHeight|| g.clientHeight;
    janela = x - 1000;
    console.log(janela); // podes tirar isto depois, só para verificares
}
window.onresize = medeJanela;
```

Dessa maneira a variável vai sendo atualizada quando a janela fôr redimensionada.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você decrementar 1000 do valor da janela sempre que for setar a variável. Por exemplo:

```
var tamanhoJanela = getTamanhoJanela() - 1000;
// 1000 - 1000 =  0
// 997  - 1000 = -3
// 1003 - 1000 =  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi seria assim:

```
var tamanho = 1000;
$(window).resize(function() {
var h = $(window).height();
tamanho += h > tamanho ? 1 : -1;
console.log(tamanho);
});
```